How to mount this vintage european sconce?
This european sconce seems to just have a sort of cross-bar for mounting. I assume there's some kind of hook that attaches to the wall to grab the cross bar. The closest thing I can find is this, but that hook looks rather shallow. Is there a smarter way to mount this kind of sconce? My hope is to not have to put some kind of big round plate on the back of it to make it cover a big box. I know it's not to code, but I'd be fine just having the wiring going straight into a hole in the sheetrock, so long as the sconce is firmly mounted to the wall itself.

Where are you?  NA requires a box for the wires and mounting.  Europe seems okay with just holes in the wall/ceiling for the wires.  Might do with chains/something similar to hold the light up, but the wires/connections must be in a covered box.

I'm in the USA. I've got an electrician who seemed fine putting the connections just into a hole in the wall before—he told me that we might have to remove it prior to selling the house, but didn't object to doing it if were comfortable with it. I'm assuming I'd do the same thing here if it's the only way to avoid putting a big brass plate over a wall box.

That electrician should be reported.  Don't wait till moving to change it.  Your insurance will denied any claims once they find it.  It is something they check to denied claims and keep the money.

Perhaps something like this could be narrow enough to be covered by the back-plate of the sconce? https://gellerlighting.com/Southwire-G19180/ There's still the question of how to mount the cross-bar on the sconce to that kind of mini junction box though. Any thoughts?

What are the dimensions of the backplate on the sconce?

The back of the lamp has the end of a standard lamp conduit held in by a nut, replace that with an extender to go though the face place of a extra-narrow junction box
connect the wires in the juction box rotate the sconce 90 degrees  screw the face plate to the box, rotate the sconce vertical.
Before doing any of that make sure you can fit 120V lamps.

Come to think of it, this is not just a good idea, it may be the only way to hang this light over an American junction box because the location of the crossbar will inevitably be across the front of the box.   There is no way to attach any hook/cleat to the wall without driving a screw into the junction box.

Could a hook be attached to one of the box closure screws, or is that against code?
